# prob with div positioning

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my code

```
while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $type = $row[0];
                $user_from = $row[1];
                $operation_to = $row[2];
                $time = $row[3];

                if($type=="vote") {
                    echo self::vote_activity($user_from,$operation_to);

                }
                else if($type=="upload_album") {
//                    echo self::upload_activity($user_from,$operation_to);
                }
                else if($type="create_account") {

                }
                else {

                }
        }
```

the function vote activity is

```
function vote_activity($user_from,$operation_to) {
        ob_start();
        global $db;
        $table = "userinformation";
        $data = array("user_id"=>$user_from);
        $result = $db->select($table,$data);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $name = $row[1]." ".$row[2];
        }

        $table = "photo_gallery";
        $data = array("photo_id"=>$operation_to);
        $result = $db->select($table,$data);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $extension = $row[6];
            $user_id = $row[0];
        }

        $source_file_path = basedir."/storage/".$user_id."/".$operation_to.".".$extension;
        $height=200;
        $width=200;
        ?>

            <div class="vote_activity_div" >
                <p class="vote_p"><a><?php echo $name?></a> vote this photo.</p>
                <img class="vote_image" src="Create_thumbnail.php?source_file_path=<?php echo $source_file_path;?>&extension=<?php echo $extension; ?>&height=<?php echo $height; ?>&width=<?php echo $width; ?>"/>
            </div>   
        <?php
        $vote_activity = ob_get_contents();
        ob_clean();
        return $vote_activity;
    }
```

The problem is that when I call this vote_activity class more than once while loop's first vote div get out of the parent div.

Comment: You are asking us to fix a structure/layout based issue, give us the code that is generated when this code has been run (both html and css please). Then we can look into it.

Comment: Use the new [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of the old `mysql`, it's better. (The PHP website says `Use of this extension is discouraged.`)

Comment: <?php echo $name?> should also be <?php echo $name;?> - mind the ";"

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to ensure the code is outputting to a parent DIV that has cleared floats etc ensuring there is no escaping. So before you run your script or however it is you are doing this, create a parent div with a class such as `vote_activity_parent`

I hope this helps!

I think it might be worth adding that you may also need to review your code to ensure it is outputting in the correct places, otherwise your script could be outputting this DIV anywhere which really isn't ideal for control.

Comment: I added an extra div and clear the float . but still not working.